# Proof that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} = \frac{1}{2}$. Is there any error?

Tags: sequences-and-series, paradoxes, cesaro-summable

So, I proved that:
$$\int f(\ln x)\ dx = x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} f^{(n)}(\ln x) \ \ \ +\ \ C$$

where $f^{(n)}$ is the nth derivative of $f$.

if we let $f(x) = e^{x}$ then $f^{(n)}(x) = e^x$ as well, so:

$$\int e^{\ln x}\ dx = x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} e^{\ln x} \ \ \ +\ \ C$$
giving us:

$$\int x\ dx = x^{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} \ \ \ +\ \ C$$

if we differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ we end up with:

$$x=2x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}$$
giving us:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Am I doing something wrong or is this valid? Because I've learned that that series is divergent, yet through this method I've proven it to be $\frac{1}{2}$ wich is also its Cesàro sum.

Comment: What you claim to have proved in the first line can't possibly be true if the series on the right-hand side doesn't converge. And that is the case here.

Comment: it would be a good idea to write up a formal derivation of the first line and see where it fails in your case

Comment: @Conrad I'll show you the proof

Comment: When you divide by $x$ in the second step, it shouldn't be $\frac{C}{x}$ not only $C$?

Comment: @rlartiga We can let $C = 0$ I think and look at a special case of the first equation I think.

Comment: @rlartiga that can bue fixed quite easily

Comment: why not just plugin -1 in geometric series instead? why is all this sing and dance needed ? not sure why you are bothering with all the above, although I admit it is nice, read more on euler's manipulation instead of running "proof" verfications by internet crowd.

Comment: @Arjang: the geometric series does not converge in $x=-1$.

Comment: @Dunkelheit : there is tag "Cesàro summable" , so yes you are right that it does not converge classically but it converges under the Cesàro summability.

Comment: @Arjang: You're right, didn't noticed it, sorry for that.

Comment: @Dunkelheit : My dear friend, asking a question is never wrong, if anything does not seem right then you MUST question it, so thank you for making me think, before replying I needed to recheck that was the case, last time I looked up "Cesàro sum" was 1993 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always keep in mind that a proof that holds for any finite case need not hold in the infinite case. In the context of your proof, the following equality holds for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$\int_a^xf\circ\log t\,dt=x\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^if^{(i)}\circ\log x-a\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^if^{(i)}\circ\log a+(-1)^n\int_a^xf^{(n+1)}\circ\log t\,dt,$$
which you can easily adapt your above proof to show via induction. However, this does not imply that the equality holds as $n\to\infty$, because $\infty$ is not a natural number - induction simply does not work in the infinite case. For your choice of $f=\exp$, we have on the right-hand side:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[x\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\exp x-a\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\exp a+(-1)^n\int_a^xt\,dt\right]$$
but this limit does not exist for any value of $x$, since the sum $\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^i$ diverges. Therefore, you can't extend this identity to the infinite case without checking that the sum on the right-hand side actually converges - otherwise the equality is meaningless.

However, when that series above *does* converge and the "remainder term" consisting of the integral on the right goes to zero, you can still use it to get some interesting results - for example, try taking $f:x\mapsto x^n$, and you can find a series expression for the following integral:
$$\int_a^x\log^nt\,dt$$

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
g_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kxf^{(k)}(\log(x))\tag1
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}g_n(x)
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kxf^{(k)}(\log(x))\tag2\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kf^{(k)}(\log(x))+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k-1}f^{(k)}(\log(x))\tag3\\[6pt]
&=f(\log(x))+(-1)^nf^{(n+1)}(\log(x))\tag4
\end{align}
$$
which gives
$$
g_n(x)=\int f(\log(x))\,\mathrm{d}x+(-1)^n\int f^{(n+1)}(\log(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag5
$$
$g_n$ tends to a limit if $f^{(n+1)}$ vanishes uniformly on compact sets. In the example in the question, $f(x)=e^x$, it does not. Instead we get
$$
g_n(x)=\frac{1+(-1)^n}2\,x^2+C_n\tag6
$$
Plugging $(6)$ into $(2)$ and dividing by $x$ gives
$$
1+(-1)^n=2\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\tag7
$$
which is a true statement, but does not lead to the sum tending to $\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

By mathematical induction $$\int_a^x f(\ln t)\ dt = \sum_{n=0}^{N}(-1)^{n} [tf^{(n)}(\ln t)]_a^x+(-1)^{N+1}\int_a^x f^{(N+1)}(\ln t) dt$$ is true for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a\gt0.$

But passing from this finite sum to an infinite series is rather technical. One obvious condition that can make this happen is restrict $f$ to be a polynomial and, then carefully extend the result for power series via [Taylor polynomials.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) This in return will capture functions like $\exp(x)$ in your construction.

Since $\lim_{t\to 0^+} t(\ln (t))^n=0$ for any $n,$ we let $a\to 0^+$ to make things bit simpler. But, we still need to prove the [uniform convergence](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Uniformly-convergent_series) for the infinite series by carefully choosing the domain of $f^{(n)}\circ\ln.$

If it is the case, I guess, after some effort we would be able to use [Abel summations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Abel_summation) to conclude the desire result.